# Prove that $\frac {(m,n){ n\choose m}}{n}$ is an integer for all integers $n\ge m\ge1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I have a question given to me by a friend.

Prove that $\frac {(m,n){n\choose m}}{n}$ is an integer for all integers $n\ge m\ge1$. Any hint??

Comment: Use bezout to express $(m,n)$ as $am+bn$

Comment: What have you tried? Also, is it $$\frac{(m, n)\binom{n}{m}}{m}$$ or is it $$\frac{(m, n)\binom{n}{m}}{n}?$$

Comment: Sorry, I m edit it.

Comment: One is divided by $m$; the other, $n$.

Comment: @Shaun, now good?

Comment: By $(m,n)$ do you mean gcd$(m,n)$?

Comment: Yes, @Narayan ${}$

Comment: Yes @Edmo38....

Comment: I was trying to remember where I have seen this problem. This is Putnam $2000$ problem

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By Bezout’s identity, there exist integers $a$ and $b$ such $gcd(m, n) =
am + bn$.

Next, notice that $$\frac{gcd(m, n)\times {n\choose m}}{n}=\frac{(am+bn)\times {n\choose m}}{n}=\frac{am\times {n\choose m}}{n}+b\times {n\choose m}= a\times {n−1 \choose m−1}+b\times{n\choose m} $$

Which is clearly an integer as $n\ge m\ge1$.

Comment: Very nice, thank you.